# how to change width of UITabbar and add scrollview in it in objective c

Tags: objective-c, xcode, xib

I am new in objective c.I create UITabbar programatically in AppleDelegate and I want to change width of tab bar. My code is look like this

```
 - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc]initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen]bounds ]];
        NewsScreen *news=[[NewsScreen alloc]initWithNibName:@"NewsScreen" bundle:nil ];
        MenuScreen *menu =[[MenuScreen alloc] initWithNibName:@"MenuScreen" bundle:nil];
        EmergencyScreen *emergency =[[EmergencyScreen alloc]initWithNibName:@"EmergencyScreen" bundle:nil ];
        NewsScreen *NewS = [[NewsScreen alloc] initWithNibName:@"NewsScreen" bundle:nil];
        CalenderScreen *calender=[[CalenderScreen alloc]initWithNibName:@"CalenderScreen" bundle:nil ];
        NotificationScreen *notification =[[NotificationScreen alloc] initWithNibName:@"NotificationScreen" bundle:nil];
        HelpScreen *help =[[HelpScreen alloc] initWithNibName:@"HelpScreen" bundle:nil];
        UINavigationController *nav1=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:menu];
        UINavigationController *nav2=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:emergency];
        UINavigationController *nav3=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:NewS];
        UINavigationController *nav4=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:calender];
        UINavigationController *nav5=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:notification];
        UINavigationController *nav6=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:help];
        nav=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:news ];
        tab=[[UITabBarController alloc]init];
        tab.viewControllers=[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:nav1,nav2,nav3,nav4,nav5,nav6, nil];
        UITabBarItem *tabItem = [[[tab tabBar] items] objectAtIndex:0];
        [tabItem setTitle:@"Menu"];
        tabItem.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"Menu.png"];
        UITabBarItem *tabItem1 = [[[tab tabBar] items] objectAtIndex:1];
        [tabItem1 setTitle:@"Emergency"];
        tabItem1.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"Emergency.png"];
        UITabBarItem *tabItem2 = [[[tab tabBar] items] objectAtIndex:2];
        [tabItem2 setTitle:@"News"];
        tabItem2.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"News.png"];
        UITabBarItem *tabItem3 = [[[tab tabBar] items] objectAtIndex:3];
        [tabItem3 setTitle:@"Calender"];
        tabItem3.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"Calender.png"];
        UITabBarItem *tabItem4 = [[[tab tabBar] items] objectAtIndex:4];
        [tabItem4 setTitle:@"Help"];
        tabItem4.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"Help.png"];
    self.window.rootViewController=nav;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

and In other viewcontroller Button Click I am doing like this.

```
AppDelegate *appDelegate = [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
        [appDelegate.window setRootViewController:appDelegate.tab];
```

But It don't show me the forth Item. Instead of it It shows me more.I just want to show forth item and add scroll in it. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

You are Using Default Tab Bar that is why it shows you more option. If you want to customize it please make your own custom tab bar so that you can modify it in whichever manner you wish to. 
Thanks.